# How to add where scope to SUM in ActiveRecord?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

I want to return Users sorted by their `mountain_routes.hearts_count` in current season.

I already wrote a method for that, but my problem is **it SUMs by all mountain_routes of the user** and I want to only sort by **SUM of users's mountain_routes in given `range`**.

```
def best_of_season
  range = start_date..end_date
  ::Db::User
    .joins(:mountain_routes)
    .where(mountain_routes: { route_type: 'regular_climbing', created_at: range })
    .select('users.id, SUM(mountain_routes.hearts_count)')
    .group('users.id')
    .distinct
    .order('SUM(mountain_routes.hearts_count) DESC')
end
```

So the problem is in this part `SUM(mountain_routes.hearts_count)`.
How to put there only mountain routes in given `range`?

I want to receive an output like this:

```
NAME   | HEARTS in this season
Thomas | 5
Dave   | 3
Erick  | 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use add an alias to `SUM(mountain_routes.hearts_count)` and use it in the order by clause:

```
::Db::User
  .joins(:mountain_routes)
  .where(mountain_routes: { route_type: :regular_climbing, created_at: range })
  .select('users.id, SUM(mountain_routes.hearts_count) AS total_mountain_routes_hearts_count')
  .group(:id)
  .order('total_mountain_routes_hearts_count DESC')
```

You must first get rid of the distinct method, as you're already grouping by the `users.id`.

Comment: I think the problem still exists because we still `SUM` *ALL* `User` `mountain_routes.hearts_count` and we want to only get `hearts_count`  from `mountain_routes` in given date. But your solution will solve second problem how to order results by result of this `SUM`